# Git push command pushes deleted files not present in local repository or commit

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git project hosted on github with only one branch (`master`) and only one contributor (me). After my initial commit I added some data files to my local repository that I didn't end up needing. I added to files and committed them at one point, but after deleting them did other commits. The deleted files are not in the remote or local repository, when I do a `git diff --stat --cached origin/master` they do not appear and `git cherry -v master` shows only the current commit I have without the files.

However, when I do a `git push origin master` git tries to compress and write the deleted data files. I cannot figure out why this is happening and how to remove the files from my staging area.

I made many commits trying to get the deleted files to not be pushed. Eventually, because I had so many commits, I backed up all of my files in a separate folder, ran a `git reset --hard origin/master` and replaced all of the files in the local repository with the backup files and then did `git add *` and `git commit -m "comment"`.

Comment: How do you know that git tries to compress and write the deleted files?

Comment: Also, git stores the history, so if there were commits containing the files, pushing them was the ritght thing to do.

Comment: @Choroba After `git push origin master` I see `Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Writing objects:  25% (11/44), 2.11 MiB | 325.00 KiB/s` but there are not that many objects in the commit and moreover eventually the write runs into an error because the deleted data files it's trying to add are too large to be hosted on github.

Comment: To remove commits from a local history, use `git rebase -i`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be running git cherry against origin master shouldnt you?  And you shouldnt be running --cached because there could be a prior commit not in your staging area, but not on origin/master, that deleted the files.

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase -i` is what I needed, thank you to @choroba for pointing that out. The files were in my local history even though they weren't in the local repository or the commit so I guess git was still trying to push them.

Additionally, thank you to @jbu who correctly noted I should've been running `git cherry origin/master -v` to see the commits waiting to be pushed.

Comment: if this issue has been resolve, please mark the answer:)